# What is the definition of an asymptotic observer?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, definition, observers

I can't find the definition of it in Wikipedia or in books on my bookshelf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, if you want to know what an observer located at coordinate position $x$ observes, you can construct a locally inertial frame at $x$ and compute the outcome of experiments (lengths, times) that the observer can do in their frame. Alternatively, you can carefully construct coordinate-independent quantities that reduce to the outcome of an experiment in a locally inertial frame, and evaluate these quantities.

In order to talk about an asymptotic observer, we need to be in a context where it makes sense to talk about an asymptotic spacetime. We need some localized distribution of matter (or curvature), and "far away" from this localized distribution the spacetime will become similar to its "average" state where the localized distribution of matter/curvature has a negligible effect. (This might be flat spacetime or it might be a model of the expanding Universe describing our actual reality). A canonical example would be a black hole in an asymptotically flat spacetime; far away from the black hole, the gravitational effect of the hole becomes arbitrarily small, and we can treat spacetime as having zero curvature.

In this context, an "asymptotic" observer refers to an observer whose position $x$ is far enough away from the distribution of matter (eg, the black hole) that we can ignore the effects of the black hole, or at least treat them as a small correction to flat spacetime. Formally, you can imagine taking the limit as $x$ approaches infinity (though the details of this limit can become important; it matters whether you want to take the spatial position of the observer to infinity at fixed time, or to take the spatial position and time to infinity at the same rate).

Comment: It's helpful.  Thanks a lot!